# Load weights from URL

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I have URL for weight file (`.h5`) of a CNN model. I want to load that weight directly to Python file and compile a keras model. How can this be done.?

Is there a direct approach or should I download the weight file and load it from disk.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a function to download weights from URL and stock it in ~/.keras/

It's the function get_file

```
from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
```

Example :

```
from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
weights_path = get_file(
            'the name under the model will be saved',
            'YOUR URL')
model.load_weights(weights_path)
```

It returns the path where the weights have been saved.
Then you can use load_weight.
But in all the case, the weights will be saved on your computer.

Comment: I loaded weight with requests library. I will try keras get_file now.