# Load weights from web without saving

Tags: deep-learning, h5py

I want to read my .h5 weights file from Dropbox and load it to re-construct my model.  Is there any way I can do this without actually downloading and saving the .h5 file locally?

This is what I have now:

```
import dropbox

access_token = 'token'
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(access_token)

weight_path = '/model_weights.h5'
_, w_file = dbx.files_download(weight_path)

model = create_model() # rebuild model structure function
model.load_weights(w_file)
```

Error message:
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'endswith'

The answer of this post [Load weights from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283444/load-weights-from-url) still download the file.